# Ubuntu 22.04.5 netplan generate > Error in network definition : invalid prefix length in address of using Public-IP but get OK on using Local-IP

Tags: networking

Configuring Ubuntu 22.04.5 network, both "netplan generate" or "netplan apply" on 00-installer-config.yaml file by this below configuration of using local-IP fortunately got success and no problem found :

networks:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
enp4s0:
dhpc4: false
addressses: [192.168.0.224/24]
routes:
- to: default
via: 192.168.0.3
nameaddresses:
addresses: [192.168.0.1,8.8.8.8]

Unfurtunately, when I just replaced the Local-IP with a Global-IP as below then error found both on "netplan generate" or "netplan apply" :

networks:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
enp4s0:
dhpc4: false
addressses: [119.18.157.14/248]
routes:
- to: default
via: 119.18.157.9
nameaddresses:
addresses: [119.18.156.10,119.18.152.10,8.8.8.8]

The error message is :

```
Error in network definition : invalid prefix length in address [119.18.157.14/248]
```

with caret sign ^ under "[".

[invalid prefix length error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdT0q.png)

Kindly please help ...

Comment: When I remove the bracket of addressses: [119.18.157.14/248]  to be addressses: 119.18.157.14/248   other error occured. Error also happened when I replace "addressses: [119.18.157.14/248]" become "addressses: - 119.18.157.14/248".

Comment: Greetings, time traveler! Ubuntu 22.04.5 is planned for the future, but does not yet exist. Perhaps you mean Ubuntu 20.04.5? That does exist.

Comment: Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Excuse me for the wrong Version. lsb_release -a got Ubuntu 22.04.2 Jammy LST version. The error still remain event I reinstalled the Ubuntu Server, Error happened when using Public-IP configuration only on *.yaml file. Please help.